# How to calculate amount over multiple months with taking start/end date into account?

Tags: excel

So what I'm trying to figure out is, let's say Object A starts on 5/20/2019 and ends on 11/19/2019 with the amount of $75,000. How can I calculate that amount from the start of that date to the end date in regards to Fiscal Year.

For example:

[image: Example]

This is the layout that  I have currently on Sheet 1. The Fiscal Months are as follows:

[image: Fiscal Year]

How would I calculate $75,000 divided out evenly from May through November taking into account that Object A started on 5/20/2019 and ended on 11/19/2019?

If anything needs to be clarified please let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.

Thank you in advance,

-Maykid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a helper column in order to make the process a bit clearer, but hopefully this will meet your needs.

First you will need to calculate the start month based upon the fiscal calendar. I'm using Excel 2013, but with newer versions you could replace the array formula with the MINIF function. You will need to replace your sheet name with the names from your workbook. 
Place this in cell C2 of the first sheet and make it an array formula by hitting CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

```
INDEX(Sheet2!A1:A13,MATCH(MIN(IF(Sheet2!B2:B13>=Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!B2:B13)),Sheet2!B1:B13,0)-1)
```

Repeat in cell C3 to calculate the end month:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A1:A13,MATCH(MIN(IF(Sheet2!B2:B13>=Sheet1!B3,Sheet2!B2:B13)),Sheet2!B1:B13,0)-1)
```

Now calculate the monthly payout by pasting this in cell C4:

```
=(B4/(MONTH(1&LEFT(C3,3))-MONTH(1&LEFT(C2, 3))))
```

This provides us with everything we need to determine if this month needs a payout and if so how much it should be. Place this formula in cell D2.Because of the helper column, this does not need to be an array formula.

```
=IF(AND(MONTH(1&LEFT(D1, 3))>=MONTH(1&LEFT($C$2, 3)), MONTH(1&LEFT(D1, 3))<=MONTH(1&LEFT($C$3, 3))), $C$4, "")
```

Drag this formula across to O2, and it should provide you with what you need.